# LC3 Assembly code to get user input string and show same string as output

Tags: assembly, lc3

I'm trying this code to be worked. But I'm always get one error.
I'm using online LC-3 Simulator. Can you please help me to find the error. Or what should I do now?

```
.orig   x3000
Lea r1, storeString

Lea r0, Student
puts

Lea r0, Userinput
puts

LOOP
getc

out
str r0, r1, 0
add r1, r1, 1
add r0, r0, -10

brz OUTSIDE

brnzp LOOP

OUTSIDE

Lea r0, Outputtext
puts

Lea r0, storeString
puts

Halt
Student .stringz "Francois Van Zyl"
Userinput .stringz "\n\nPlease enter a text: "
Outputtext .stringz "The text you have typed is: "
storeString .blkw 99

.end
```

Eorror Message is:

```
Oh no! You've got an error in your assembly code:
at line 34: Invalid numeric literal: '99'
```

Comment: Try `#99` there instead.

Comment: Oh no! You've got an error in your assembly code:
at line 14: while parsing the offset for a str: the offset '0' is not a valid numeric literal, but I can't find it in the symbol table either; did you misspell a label name?

..............this error occurs now

Comment: Ok, try `#0` there.

Comment: Oh no! You've got an error in your assembly code:
at line 14: while parsing the offset for a str: the offset '0' is not a valid numeric literal, but I can't find it in the symbol table either; did you misspell a label name?

This error now happens. Ok this code works when I'm changing my compiler and using different compiler. So maybe the problem is with the compiler not the code.

Comment: Some online LC3 compilers will have very different rules when dealing with immediate values.